# $scope value not updating in view when $scope value is changed in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, view

I have a function which uses papaparse.js to immediately get the content of a .csv file selected via a file input as a JSON object list, I then pass this list to a $scope which I console.log.

This is triggered on a button click and works, the issue is the view can't immediately see this $scope has been updated until another action happens, such as clicking the button again, or clicking another button which calls an empty $scope function.

HTML View:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">        

    <input id="csvfile" type="file" accept=".csv">

    <button type="button" ng-click="readDataList()">
        Preview Data                
    </button>

    {{dataList}}

</div>
```

And the .js is

```
var App = angular.module('App', ["ui.bootstrap"]);

App.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {   

    $scope.dataList;

    $scope.readDataList = function ()
    {
        var myfile = $("#csvfile")[0].files[0];
        var json = Papa.parse(myfile,
            {
                header: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true,
                complete: function (results)
                {
                    $scope.dataList = results.data;
                    console.log($scope.dataList);
                }
            });        
    };     

});
```

The list is in the console as soon as the button is clicked, but won't appear in the view unless I clikc the button again.

If I add into the contoller the following:

```
$scope.testScope = 'hello';

$scope.changeScope = function () {
    $scope.testScope = 'goodbye';
}
```

and in the view have the new $scope displayed and the function on a new ng-click this works immediately displaying the new value as soon as the button is clicked. But it doesn't work for the data from the csv even though it appears in console.

Comment: I'm not familiar with papaparse.js, but is this just another flavor of the common problem where the `complete` function (in this case) is happening outside the Angular digest cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$scope.$apply();` after the line `$scope.dataList = results.data;`

Your Papa.parse function is out of the scope of angular, due to which any changes done in its callback are not captured by angular. So you have to manually trigger the new digest cycle with $scope.$apply() function so that angular checks if anything has  changed in its scope and updates the view.

Read this for more detailed information  http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: Even if it works, using `$scope.$apply()` without a function is bad advice. Using `$timeout` is much better advice or at the very least have a function that is passed to `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: I don't have any queries, I was commenting on your answer because it gives sub-optimal advice.  Using `$scope.$apply()` the way you suggested will for sure throw a bunch of errors about it already being in the digest cycle.  On a side note, your article is really old and it also agrees with me if you read the last section.

Comment: @BShaps What would be the best way to have .$apply() trigger on click same time as the other method with the other scope passed to it?

Comment: @Vereonix If you want to make sure you trigger the digest cycle without any risk of errors, wrap the update to the variable (or the whole function) in a `$timeout` with a 0 delay.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to resolve the issue by using `$rootScope`, I have used `$rootScope` and the value is automatically updating the view (HTML template).

Controller:

```
$rootScope.myVariable = 'update label'
```

Now, if you update the value of `myVariable` via any click/change events the updated value will be updated in the HTML template.

HTML file:

```
<h3>{{myVariable}}</h3>
```